# How to use a progress bar for time consuming simple function

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I have a simple function without any for loop. But this function takes quit a long time to complete. So I need a progress bar to show while the process is running. All the examples I have seen have a for loop in which they increment the progress bar. Unluckily I don't have a for loop. Here is my code :

```
//Form1.cs
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Connection cConnection = new Connection();
    textBox2.Text = cConnection.connect();  
 }

 //Program.cs
  public class Connection
    {
        public string connect()
        {
            try
            {


                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                string command = "dir /s /b /o:gn";
                startInfo.Arguments = command; // this will take a quit long time to complete
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                return "Done"
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return "";
            }

        }
    }
```

All I am doing is executing a command in command prompt which take a long time to complete. How to update the progress bar

Answer (score 3):

Not only do you not have loops, you have no events available to you.  There is no feedback mechanism from `dir` to your program.

That leaves you without any possibility of updating a progress bar with any degree of accuracy.

If you wish to re-implement the `dir` functionality (e.g. in C#), you could have your implementation provide a feedback mechanism that approximates the actual progress.  For example, if the top level directory contains 10 subdirectories, you could update the progress bar by 10% when each is completed with processing.  It would not be entirely accurate, but it would be an improvement over no progress updates.

Answer (score 0):

I will propose a workaround solution, but from my perspective this is not a good idea. since we don't have feedback from `dir` we can use timer as follows.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer t1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    int counter = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        t1.Interval = 1000;
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 100;
        textBox1.Text = "Done";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        t1.Start();
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            t1.Tick += new EventHandler(t1_Tick);
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            string command = "dir /s /b /o:gn";
            startInfo.Arguments = command; // this will take a quit long time to complete
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;              
            t1.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    void t1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter = counter + 10;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(counter);
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ProgressPercentage <= 90)
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

}
```

Comment: Unless you have some sense of how much time this will typically take, this is not a good idea at all.  The progress bar will be in no proportion to the actual progress.

Comment: This is not at all working, the progress bar is updating only after the command is executed

Comment: @EricJ. You are correct the above code is not proportional to actual progress, but as some how the code conveys some progress is going on

Comment: @sameer the code should work initially back ground worker starts as async later we are enabling the timer so both will execute concurrently later we stop the timer once we complete the dir command so at this time the remaing 10% progress completes

Comment: I can do that without using background thread by incrementing the progress bar in between the statements

Comment: oh really that's great you can use progress-bar without back ground thread...)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but I had a similar problem, and it might help others in the future. As the others above me said, you could create a progress bar, but estimating the time of a certain process is both difficult and time-consuming, and it also could be easialy inaccurate. However, if you don't have to use a progress bar and just want to inform the user that the program needs a longer time to execute a process, you have other options.

Instead of using a progress bar, you could use a **loading indicator** so you don't need to calculate the time needed for the process. Essentially, instead of progressing a bar, you'll need an animation that you loop in the background until that certain process is done.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2004/october/advanced-basics-building-a-progress-bar-that-doesn-t-progress) explains how to build a loading indicator in depth, you might find it helpful.